# Need to access the asp.net server control in java script on load

Tags: javascript

I need to access the asp.net custom control in java script on page load by using the Client ID.

I tried with this but its giving the null value.

```
document.getElementById('<% =customControl.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: So far I recall, there is no space between `%` and `=` in the `<%=` nugget.

Comment: where is your JS code? Does it appear at the end of the HTML after the .NET control. If not it will not find it

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error.

replace `<% =customControl.ClientID%>`

to

`<%=customControl.ClientID%>`

(remove that space over there)

(and make sure there's an element in the `.aspx` file with `runat="server"` and `id="customControl"`).

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

if its a custom control which you have created do like below

in jQuery

```
$('#<%= customControl.FindControl("txtDate").ClientID%>').val();
```

in javascript

```
document.getElementById('<% =customControl.FindControl("txtDate").ClientID %>')
```

where `txtDate` is the control within the custom control